# How can I generically deserialize PropertyInfo with Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json.net

I need to serialize many different objects with Json.NET. I really have no control over the objects being provided, so I'm generically serializing and de-serializing  with [TypeNameHandling.All](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm).

However, some of these objects cannot be de-serialized. Specifically, I am getting some System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo types. I'd like to handle these in a standardized fashion, as I am unaware of the target type at the time of de-serialization. Nor do I care, as long as the output object type is correct.

I've attempted a [CustomCreationConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomCreationConverter.htm) typed to PropertyInfo that is defined in [JsonSerializerSettings](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm). However, even though CanConvert() is returning true, the CustomCreationConverter's ReadJson() is never utilized.

The end result is the same as if I had never used the CustomCreationConverter:

> ISerializable type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' does not
>   have a valid constructor. To correctly implement ISerializable a
>   constructor that takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext
>   parameters should be present.

I need the CustomCreationConverter to handle the ReadJson so that I can manually search for the PropertyInfo myself.

**After more investigation, it appears that the Converters I am adding to the JsonSerializerSettings are not being utilized at all. If I use the DeserializeObject overload that includes the Type and collection of JsonConverter, the Converter will be utilized. I am unsure as to what the Converters supplied to the JsonSerializerSettings are used for, but I would expect they would work as I intend in this situation.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Json
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
                TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
                Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new PropertyInfoConverter(), },
            };
            var propertyInfo = typeof(Test).GetProperty("Name");

            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propertyInfo, jsonSerializerSettings);
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized, jsonSerializerSettings);
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class PropertyInfoConverter : CustomCreationConverter<PropertyInfo>
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(PropertyInfo).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }

        public override PropertyInfo Create(Type objectType)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return null; // This is never invoked, but is where I would attempt to find the PropertyInfo via Reflection searching.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to serialize the whole PropertyInfo object? Is property name not enough? It might be hard and tricky as PropertyInfo has reference to Type and Type has reference to Assembly and Assembly has a lot of different references to others objects...

Comment: Specifically this is for injecting a new caching provider into a very old legacy system. Serialization is a requirement of the new provider's caching engine. The provider has to replicate the previous provider's functionality verbatim as far as cache access is concerned.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention the exception `ISerializable type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' does not have a valid constructor. To correctly implement ISerializable a constructor that takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext parameters should be present. Path '', line 1, position 287.`

Comment: Yeah, added a bit more on what I'm expecting to happen.

Comment: I'm guessing that your converters are not being used because the deserializer is relying upon the ISerializable interface instead.

Comment: Do your requirements allow for changing the serialized output?

Comment: They unfortunately did not. I was completely at the mercy of the system. Basically was inheriting a legacy system with a questionable caching system replacing it with Redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the API you need to conform to must input/output a `PropertyInfo` object you can cut out the converter and use a new class to save only the information necessary to recreate the object.

```
private class PropertyInfoData
{
    public string TypeName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string PropertyName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static PropertyInfoData FromProperty(PropertyInfo p)
    {
        return new PropertyInfoData()
        {
            TypeName = p.DeclaringType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
            PropertyName = p.Name,
        };
    }

    public PropertyInfo ToProperty()
    {
        return Type.GetType(this.TypeName).GetProperty(this.PropertyName);
    }
}
```

Then you can de/serialize it like this:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
    //Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new PropertyInfoConverter(), },
};
var propertyInfo = typeof(Test).GetProperty("Name");

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PropertyInfoData.FromProperty(propertyInfo), jsonSerializerSettings);
var deserialized = ((PropertyInfoData)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized, jsonSerializerSettings)).ToProperty();
```

Here is a really crude (the read method isn't very robust) example using a converter as well:

```
public class PropertyInfoConverter : JsonConverter
{
public override bool CanWrite
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return typeof(PropertyInfo).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
}

public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    string propertyName = null;
    string assemblyName = null;
    string typeName = null;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
        {
            string value = reader.Value.ToString();

            switch (reader.Value.ToString())
            {
                case "Name":
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    break;
                case "AssemblyName":
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        assemblyName = reader.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    break;
                case "ClassName":
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        typeName = reader.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }       
    }

    return Type.GetType(typeName + ", " + assemblyName).GetProperty(propertyName);
}

/// <inheritdoc />
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    // When the property "CanWrite" returns false this method is never expected to be called.
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}

Note, in order to force the deserialize method to use the custom converter you should call the generic version of it like this:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PropertyInfo>(serialized, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

The same is true in your example which is why you weren't hitting your break point.

Comment: Interesting, wrapping the offenders to avoid a direct serialization instead of using a custom converter. I'm assuming then to handle  generic types it would just be a type check on either direction and handling it appropriately.

Comment: If I needed a converter I would use similar code internally in the converter. You would have trouble using the `CustomCreationConverter` way it was intended because in the `Create`method you don't have enough information to reliable create a `PropertyInfo` instance. It is abstract and you are likely serializing an instance of `RuntimePropertyInfo` which isn't public. I would inherit from the `JsonConverter` class instead. If you want to continue using the default serialization override the `CanWrite` property and return false from it always.